# wxPython import work with cmd but not within a *.py

Tags: python, wxpython

Good day,

I just started to work with wxpython for a few more features then tkinter, but ran into a problem.
I installed wxpython via pip without errors.

Now the following code work if I type it to Windows cmd

```py
import wx

app = wx.App()

frame = wx.Frame(None, title="Simple")
frame.Show()

app.MainLoop()
```

but if I use `F:\guiwx.py` i got:

```
  File "F:\guiwx.py", line 1, in <module>
    import wx
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wx'
```

Even after reinstall the problem stays the same.

I have only one version of Python installed (**2.7.15**) which I need for work.

What is going wrong here?

Comment: How are you executing your file `guiwx.py`??

Comment: with python F:\guiwx.py it workes.
Buy why tkinter don't need that python infront?

Comment: @Dystharia Hard to say, when we can't see the script you've run successfully without the `python` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the command:

```
python F:\guiwx.py
```

and it should work.